# How to repair "handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202" c# selenium error

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im new at programming and I only found how to repair it in python.
This code was working for first but when i tried it later error appear.

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Threading;
namespace AternosServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            options.AddArgument("--ignore-ssl-errors");
            options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://aternos.org/go/");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("user")).SendKeys("X");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("X");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("login")).Click();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://aternos.org/server/");
                      

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I run your code 4 times using selenium with c#.
also sign up in your site - https://aternos.org/servers/

after that put my credential and test it, and it is working fine, no any issue found.
No need to write last line of your code -

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://aternos.org/server/");
```

when you click on login button it will redirect on that page.

let me know if any issue regarding selenium with c#.

Comment: oh thx I don't know maybe it's because certificate in web isn't accepted by program but really thx.